# The app crashes when I try to add a picture to my favorites collection. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, layout, uicollectionview, reloaddata

When I add an image from the TattooIdeas screen to a collection in the FavoriteTattooIdeas screen, the application crashes with the error "UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-null layout parameter".

class TattooIdeasViewController: UIViewController {
// some code

//I think the error is in this part of the code.

'''
@objc private func addBarButtonTapped(){

```
    let selectedPhotos = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.reduce([], { (photosss, indexPath) -> [Result] in
        var mutablePhotos = photosss
        let photo = photos[indexPath.item]
        mutablePhotos.append(photo)
        return mutablePhotos
    })
    
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "\(selectedPhotos!.count) фото будут добавлены в альбом", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let add = UIAlertAction(title: "Добавить", style: .default) { (action) in
        
        let favVC = FavouritesTattooIdeaController()
        favVC.photos.append(contentsOf: selectedPhotos ?? [])
        favVC.collectionView.reloadData()
        
        self.refresh()
    }
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Отменить", style: .cancel) { (action) in
    }
    alertController.addAction(add)
    alertController.addAction(cancel)
    present(alertController, animated: true)
}
```

'''

if I declare let favVC = FavoritesTattooIdeaController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout()), then the application does not crash, but the pictures are not displayed in the collectionView on the FavoriteTattooIdeas screen.

class FavouritesTattooIdeaController: UICollectionViewController {

```
var photos = [Result]()

private let enterSearchTermLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "You haven't add a photos yet"
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
    collectionView.register(FavouritesTattooIdeaCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: FavouritesTattooIdeaCell.reuseId)
    collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1
    
    setupEnterLabel()
}

private func setupEnterLabel() {
    collectionView.addSubview(enterSearchTermLabel)
    enterSearchTermLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    enterSearchTermLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    enterSearchTermLabel.isHidden = photos.count != 0
    return photos.count
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: FavouritesTattooIdeaCell.reuseId, for: indexPath) as! FavouritesTattooIdeaCell
    let googlePhoto = photos[indexPath.item]
    cell.googlePhoto = googlePhoto
    return cell
}
```

}

```
// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
```

extension FavouritesTattooIdeaController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = collectionView.frame.width
    return CGSize(width: width/3 - 1, height: width/3 - 1)
}
```

}

Comment: It's unclear. What's the relation between `TattooIdeasViewController` & `FavouritesTattooIdeaController`? That's two `UIViewController`.

Comment: The TattooIdeasViewController controller displays images from Google, which can be selected and added to the "favorites" album using @objc private func addBarButtonTapped() .
This album is located in the FavoritesTattooIdeaController, maybe I specified the layout parameter incorrectly somewhere and therefore the application crashes and gives the corresponding error?

Comment: When you write `let favVC = FavouritesTattooIdeaController()`, you create a new  `FavouritesTattooIdeaController`, I don't see you showing it. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: when I write "let favVC = FavouritesTattooIdeaController()" then I get access to that controller's properties (photos). I pass selectedPhotos to this array
And the transition to FavoritesTattooIdeaController is carried out through another button and selector @objc private func showFavVC() {
         let favVC = FavoritesTattooIdeaController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
         self.navigationController?.pushViewController(favVC, animated: true)
     }

Comment: No, you are missing the OOP concepts. `let favVC` is different in the two calls. It's like having 2 strings. they are of the same class, but aren't the same objects.

Comment: I fixed in showFavVC() let favVC to favoriteVC , but still selected photos are not added to favorites

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the fact that `FavouritesTattooIdeaController()` is short for `FavouritesTattooIdeaController.init()`. So here, you are creating a new object. Same for `FavouritesTattooIdeaController(collectionViewLayout:)` and `FavouritesTattooIdeaController.init(collectionViewLayout:)`.

What's happening:

You are in your `UIAlertAction` creating a new object of `FavouritesTattooIdeaController`.
Then, later you are creating a new `FavouritesTattooIdeaController` to show it. But they aren't related to each other.

Imagine that a `init()` is like getting a new empty box.
So you create a new box, put your favorites photos, andd since you don't use it, you just discard it afterwards.
Then, when you want to display your favorites, you create again a new empty  box, and expect to have the previous items put inside the other box. See the issue?

To solve the issue:

You need to keep inside `TattooIdeasViewController` an array of `selectedPhotos`.
And put it to `FavouritesTattooIdeaController` when you'll show it.

OR

Use the same variable `FavouritesTattooIdeaController` (be it a property of  `TattooIdeasViewController`), so you add each time the photos, and it will keep all of thems.